# Elasticsearch configuration using Nlog

Tags: elasticsearch, nlog

I'm using Nlog to write logs to Elasticsearch, which works just fine. The problem is that aggregations don't work because the fielddata on the property I try to aggregate is set to false by default. The error I get reads as follows:

> illegal_argument_exception Reason: "Fielddata is disabled on text
>   fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [level] in order to load
>   fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index

Since an index is created by Nlog, I would like it to map certain properties in a way that they can be later aggregated. Is it possible to configurte Nlog so that the error is gone and aggregations start working?

Comment: See also https://github.com/markmcdowell/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch/issues/89